# NSFileManager does not properly work

Tags: objective-c, foundation

I want to move 2 files with `NSFileManager`, but it isn't moving my files:

at `myfolder` There are 5 text file, that i will remove all this files

My code:

```
BOOL isDir;
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/volume/netrt/myfolder/" isDirectory:&isDir]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:@"/volume/netrt/myfolder/*" error:nil]; // for delete all files
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] movItemAtPath:@"/rdns/macross/text1.txt" toPath:@"/volume/netrt/myfolder/" error:nil];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] movItemAtPath:@"/rdns/macross/text2.txt" toPath:@"/volume/netrt/myfolder/" error:nil];
}
```

The folder `myfolder` already exists. What is my mistake?

thank you so much

Comment: Why are you using the [tag:c] tag?  This is an Objective-C question.

Comment: Also consider adding brackets around your `if` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's very likely other issues going on, but for starters, the `toPath:` needs an actual file name.

`[[NSFileManager defaultManager] movItemAtPath:@"/rdns/macross/text1.txt" toPath:@"/volume/netrt/myfolder/text1.txt" error:nil];`

Add "text1.txt" to the end of your `toPath:`.

[NSFileManager documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac//documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:)

Comment: You will have to add text2.txt to the second statement, just like you have to add text1.txt to the first...

Comment: thank you. this is move files but not remove any files `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:@"/volume/netrt/myfolder/*" error:nil]; ` i will remove all files at `myfolder` dir before move 2 files

Comment: @Wlz-dsh0 So what error are you getting when you pass the method one?

Comment: According to the docs, it will delete the file.  The moveItemAtPath: method returns a boolean and an error that help you determine if it failed and why.  That will help you solve your issue.

Comment: @Bek so how can i fixe this problem. i want delete all files at   `myfolder` before move any files to this folder

Comment: Fairly sure NSFileManager doesn't support using wildcards in the path. So you have to list all the files and subdirectories and call remove for each of them. You might find this [NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/nsfilemanager/) useful.

Comment: @Wlz-dsh0 that is a different question than your original one.

Comment: @Tobias thank you but this files is random.Don't have a specific name.

Comment: @Wlz-dsh0 The easiest thing is to probably delete the folder and recreate it. Deleting the folder will delete all its contents.

Comment: @Tobias oh yes good idea. also in the past i see somethings like it, but could you please let me now how to do it. thank you

Comment: @Wlz-dsh0 I'll see if I can create a sample playground for you tomorrow.

Comment: @Tobias still waiting, and could you please give me your email address

Comment: @Wlz-dsh0 sorry been really busy. Were you not able to make any progress after reading the NSHIPSTER article?

Comment: @Tobias  NSHIPSTER? i try somethings but failed i really need your help, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You know, the `error` parameter isn't there for you to ignore. You are encountering an issue and still passing `nil`?! Seriously?

If you had looked at what the `NSFileManager` told you the error was you wouldn't need to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

Below is code for a demo playground that you should be able to use to figure out your question.

```
// Demo Playground for StackOverflow Question
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30807497/nsfilemanager-does-not-properly-work/30807624?noredirect=1#comment50017381_30807624

// Shows how to recursively remove all file in a directory by removing the directory and then recreating it.

// Please see the main function first for more explanation


import Cocoa

//Creates Fake Directory with Fake Files
func createFakeDirectoryAtPath(path: String) -> NSError? {

    var isDir = ObjCBool(false)
    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path, isDirectory: &isDir) {
        println("INFO> Will not create fake directory, file exists at: \(path).")
        return nil
    }

    var createDirError: NSError?
    NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(path, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil, error: &createDirError)

    if let error = createDirError {
        return error
    }
    println("\tINFO> Created Fake Directory Named: \(path.lastPathComponent).")

    for filename in ["one.txt", "two.jpg", "three.png", "four.doc", "five.txt", "six.mp3"] {
        let filepath = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent(filename)
        if NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(filepath, contents: nil, attributes: nil) {
            println("\t\tINFO> Created Fake File Named: \(filename).")
        }
    }


    return nil
}

func createFakeDirectoryStructureAtPath(path: String) -> Bool {

    //Create base directory
    let createDirError = createFakeDirectoryAtPath(path)
    if let error = createDirError {
        println("!ERROR> " + error.localizedDescription)
        return false
    }

    //Creates fake directories
    for dirname in ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"] {
        let subDirPath = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent(dirname)
        let createSubDirError = createFakeDirectoryAtPath(subDirPath)

        if let error = createSubDirError {
            println("!ERROR> " + error.localizedDescription)
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}


//Removes a directory at all it's contents
func removeDirectoryAtPath(path: String) {

    var isDir = ObjCBool(false)
    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path, isDirectory: &isDir) && isDir {

        var removeDirError: NSError?
        NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(path, error: &removeDirError)

        if let error = removeDirError {
            println("!ERROR> " + error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

}


//This is where the demo execution will begin.

// Start by opening the path that will contain the fake directory.
// Then one by one turn use the boolean controls to turn on each step and explore the results of each step.
// Then look at the code to figure out how it's doing what it's doing.

func main() {
    //Controls Location of Fake Directory
    let fakeDirectoryPath = "~/fake-directory".stringByExpandingTildeInPath

    assert(fakeDirectoryPath.lastPathComponent == "fake-directory", "This code will remove the directory and all contents in the directory at path: \(fakeDirectoryPath). If you are ABSOLUTELY sure you want to do this, please update this assertion. Note playground code will automatically execute so you could go up a creek without a paddle if you remove this assertion.")

    println("Open this path: \(    fakeDirectoryPath.stringByDeletingLastPathComponent)\n\n")

    //These Booleans control whether or not execute a step of the demo.

    let setupFakeDirectory = false
    let removeFakeDirectory = false
    let createEmptyDirectory = false
    let removeEmptyDirectory = false


    //Create Fake Directory and Subdirectories with fake files in them.
    if setupFakeDirectory {

        removeDirectoryAtPath(fakeDirectoryPath)

        let success = createFakeDirectoryStructureAtPath(fakeDirectoryPath)
        if success {
            println("Created Fake Directory Structure at Path: \(fakeDirectoryPath)")
        } else {
            println("Didn't Create Fake Directory Structure At Path: \(fakeDirectoryPath)")
        }
    }

    //Removes the fake directory structure
    if removeFakeDirectory {
        removeDirectoryAtPath(fakeDirectoryPath)
    }

    if createEmptyDirectory {
        var createDirError: NSError?
        NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(fakeDirectoryPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil, error: &createDirError)

        if let error = createDirError {
            println("!ERROR> " + error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }

    if removeEmptyDirectory {
        removeDirectoryAtPath(fakeDirectoryPath)
    }
}

main()
```

Comment: thank you, but why fake directory.
This makes me dizzy

Comment: @Wlz-dsh0 just to show it'll delete everything in the directory too.

Comment: @Wlz-dsh0 I don't know off hand. But NSFileManager should have documentation for createDirectoryAtPath

Comment: this code `NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);`  but i dot know how can i set wner, group, and permissions.

Comment: Several NSFileManager method take a dictionary of Attributes. You can use construct a dictionary using the [appropriate attribute key](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/File_Attribute_Keys) to specify owner, group, and permission.

Comment: @Wlz-dsh0 Hey can you write down exactly what you need to do and share a link to it? Here's an example of what I mean - https://gist.github.com/tobiasoleary/30c1b414d1c7f2f97edc. If you can't share a link on github because of your rep you might be able to list the domain and path separately to get around StackExchange's URL detector.

Comment: Do a whois on tobiasoleary.com and you can get my email. I don't feel comfortable posting it here. I think you should create a new question about how to create and delete files with user root and group wheel.